# c random number on time

Tags: c, random

Why does this program only generate numbers from 0.1-0.2. It needs to generate numbers from 0-1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*declare pseudo-random number */
    float random;
    srand(time(NULL));

    random = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    printf("The random number is %f\n", random);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling using gcc on a mac.

Comment: It's always around .16 for me too, GCC, OS X 10.7.

Comment: Run it again after a second or two. The code seems fine to me.

Comment: Very weird, any ideas as to why?

Comment: The code works fine for me. Try it here for example: http://codepad.org/DrR4EdUZ

Comment: Run a loop that generates more than one random number. There's no guarantee about the *first* value of the RNG, only about large sequences of numbers.

Comment: Are you running it in windows?

Comment: To generate a random number 0 or 1 it is sufficient to use this line: printf("rand num is %d\n",rand()%2); Just print the rand() values and see if those are changing.

Comment: @LewisElliott "I'm compiling using gcc on a mac." <- Obviously, OP is running this on Windows. He has an OS X to Windows cross-toolchain installed.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: the first number is "just" as random as a sequence... what I'm trying to say is that your comment is misleading. generating only one random number is fine.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: it's very plausible that the first number is just the seed value itself, so its randomness may be highly dependent on the way you seed.

Comment: I have the source code for rand() and srand() that's used in Windows. But I dont know if I can post it for you all to see. Will I be sued by MS for that?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: huh? another good reason not to use windows..

Comment: @LewisElliott you have accepted the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code seems fine to me. Try to generate more than one number and see then:

```
for(i=1; i<100; i++){
  random = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
  printf("%f\n", random);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int random_seed;
    void __cdecl srand(int data){
       random_seed = data;
    }

    int __cdecl rand (
            void
            )
    {
            return( ((random_seed = random_seed * 214013L
                + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff );
    }
```

This is the implementation of srand() and rand() on windows CRT. I am not sure if I will be sued by MS for this.

Clearly, you might have to call rand() many times to get a proper value between 0 and 1. no matter what time() returns[as it will only be set into random_seed].

Comment: Please, you're not even bothering them with this. It's more the people who discover an undocumented function and spread word. Later, when MS wants to remove said function, they can't because it will break too many professional applications.

Comment: @chris thanks. I just don't want to get into legal troubles. I am having enough of troubles already. :P

Answer (score 0):

The above code went fine for me(gcc in ubuntu) i.e. my output was varying from 0.1 to 1. Try to run the program three-four times an then see the output